# Как подключиться к Apache Tomcat 8.0 серверу из интернета?

Tags: java, веб-программирование, apache, tomcat

Есть веб-приложение, запускаю *Apache Tomcat 8.0*, из локальной сети через `localhost:8080` все работает прекрасно. Даже могу зайти через *айфон*, который подключен к тому же вай фаю, и приложение работает в мобильном сафари.

Но как только я подключаюсь непосредственно к своему *ip* на тому же порту - соединения нету. Гуглил - пишут открыть порты через *брандмауэр*. Открыл, но без изменений.

В чем может быть причина? Может, надо что-то настроить в самом *apache*?

Стоить сказать, что я также пробовал подключаться к *мтс интернету* через режим модема на *айфоне*, чтоб поэкспериментировать с разными провайдарами, вдруг дело в этом, но к своему *мтс ip* тоже не могу подключиться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы получаете IP адрес внутри сети своего провайдера. В интернет вы выходите через прокси-сервер своего провайдера. Ваш IP адрес не существует в Интернет, он спрятан за прокси-сервером. Вам нужно заказать у своего провайдера услугу "статический IP адрес", который будет виден из внешней сети - Интернета.

Comment: Спасибо, а это точно из-за этого? Мне казалось у меня статический IP, так как не меняется адрес никогда. Позвоню провайдеру, закажу. Надеюсь действительно дело в этом.

Comment: Вы были правы. Надо было лишь заказать статический адрес. Танцы с бубном вокруг портов в том же брандмауэре не нужны. Достаточно просто запустить Tomcat сервер, по крайней мере с версией 8.